# If not following correct procedure?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm working on a Content Management System, and so far so good.

I'm trying to get the system to work with a maintenance mode system.
This is the code in the script to display the maintenance stuff:

```
if ($maintenance['value'] == "1") {?>
    <div id="content">
     <div id="errmsg">
      <?php echo $maintenance['notes']; ?>
     </div>
    </div>
<? } else {?>

   <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
   <hr /><br />
   <div id="content">
    <?php echo $contents; 
     if (!$content) { 
      include    ('includes/error/404.php');}?>
   </div>               
<? } ?>
```

I can verify that the $maintenance['value'] variable is working as it should, but this portion o the script isn't working as it should. The value is currently set to 1, but it still displays the stuff in the else.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why two `}` in when closing your `else` statement?

Comment: must have been an artifact when copying, I couldn't see the other closing bracket

Comment: Also, I recommend not using short php tags. Use the full <?php ?>.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I usually convert to full before I move the code to production :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Cassy's proposed notation. My remarks:

I'm not really sure how PHP really handles datatypes but I just checked [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and according to this, your expression should evaluate to true, even if `$maintenance['value']` holds the integer `1` (you are comparing it to the string `"1"`).

What is the other value, `$maintenance['value']` can hold? "0"? If so, why not just assign `TRUE` and `FALSE` to the variable, to be on the save side? Anyway, maybe you can try just to write your expression like this:

```
<?php if ($maintenance['value']) : ?>
```

This evaluates to `TRUE` if `$maintenance['value']` holds any of these values:

- true
- 1
- any integer != 0
- "1"
- any string != "0"

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use a different syntax. Instead of opening curly brackets, you can use

```
<?php if ($maintenance['value'] == "1") : ?>

    <!-- HTML STUFF HERE -->

<?php ELSE: ?>

    <!-- more html stuff here -->

<?php ENDIF; ?>
```

From my experience, the PHP parser can parse this better.

See also [the PHP manual for the alternative syntax](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: interestingly, this didn't do anything :s

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have an extra } following your `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

How about reversing the approach?

```
if (!isset($maintenance['value'])) { ?>

// echo normal non-maintenance stuff

<?php } else { ?>

// display maintenance stuff

<?php

}
```

That way you know whether the `maintenance` variable is being set, or not. And hopefully, perhaps with a `echo "<pre>" . print_r(get_defined_vars(),true) . "</pre>";` see why.

Also, just because I'm typically atrocious and amnesiac at first-runs through `if/else` statements, are you sure you're using a comparison, rather than assignment, operator in the live code?

Post edited in response to following comment from OP:

> that might not work, the value in the database is either 1 or 0. I should have made this clearer in OP.

If you know that $maintenance['value'] is boolean, 1 or 0, then why not use that knowledge and make:

```
if ($maintenance['value'] == "0") { ?>

// echo normal non-maintenance stuff

<?php } elseif ($maintenance['value'] == "1") {

// display maintenance stuff

<?php } else { 

echo "<pre>" . print_r(get_defined_vars(),true) . "</pre>";

}
```

Then you know exactly what's happening. Though not, of course, necessarily *why*. Which is probably the point of your question.

Comment: that might not work, the value in the database is either 1 or 0. I should have made this clearer in OP.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, you're trying to compare between an int and a string. You can change everything to either using "1" or 1, or "0" or 0. An alternative and better method is to use the type-specific compare operators such as `===` or `!==` to match both value and type; and use the boolean terms true and false to make it painfully obvious to both yourself and the interpreter what you're trying to do.

You could also try using `define("MAINTENANCE", true);` for example, to make sure the value doesn't change halfway through the script. Though then again, this could make it more difficult to change the settings server-side unless you write new values to the file. Though then there might be issues with you writing while the server is trying to read the file for another client...